# Windows 10 Task Bar Defaulting to first icon regardless of the selected Icon

Tags: windows-10, icons, office365, chrome-remote-desktop, bug

My Desktop has developed an odd bug.
When I select an icon from the task bar, instead of opening up the program a white box will encompass the first icon on the task bar (in my case Microsoft Word) and bring up the recent documents menu as if I have right clicked on that Icon.

The only way I have found to stop this, albeit temporarily is to hold shift while selecting another Icon, this may fix the problem for a few minutes to a few hours.
Now I do not know if this is occurring because of Windows 10 or if it because I am remoting into my desktop via Chrome Remote Desktop, or if it has something to do with Office 365.

Has anyone come across something similar and do they have a fix?

Comment: Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator and run in order: dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-irmage  /restorehealth   and then SFC /SCANNOW  .  Restart after both are complete and test.

Comment: I'll ask my tech provider to try and we'll go from there, was hoping it would be a fix I could do, but not allowed Admin Access.